# mockito: The class [X] not prepared for test

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, mockito, powermockito

After migrating my JAVA EE app. (Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework) from Ant to Maven I have some errors executing the Junit test that before the migration were working fine

```
org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException: 
The class org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils not prepared for test.
To prepare this class, add class to the '@PrepareForTest' annotation.
In case if you don't use this annotation, add the annotation on class or  method level. 

    at org.powermock.api.mockito.expectation.reporter.MockitoPowerMockReporter.classNotPrepared(MockitoPowerMockReporter.java:31)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockTypeValidatorFactory$DefaultMockTypeValidator.validate(MockTypeValidatorFactory.java:38)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.AbstractMockCreator.validateType(AbstractMockCreator.java:18)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMock(MockCreator.java:57)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:47)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:71)
    at com.tdk.iot.controller.criteria.ProductCriteriaPeriodControllerTest.setUpTest(ProductCriteriaPeriodControllerTest.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

and here my class:

```
  package com.tdk.iot.controller.criteria;

    import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
    import org.mockito.Mock;
    import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
    import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
    import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.ui.ExtendedModelMap;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils;
    import org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils;



    import com.tdk.iot.domain.formBeans.ProductCriteriaPeriodForm;
    import com.tdk.iot.services.client.HelpDeskService;
    import com.tdk.iot.services.client.ProductCriteriaPeriodService;



    /**
     * @author amadeu
     *
     */

    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = {
            "classpath:com/tdk/iot/services/testServiceContext.xml",
            "classpath:com/tdk/iot/controller/apply/applyController.xml",
            "classpath:com/tdk/iot/config/testApplicationContext.xml",
            "classpath:com/tdk/iot/config/testDatabaseMessageSource.xml",
            "classpath:com/tdk/iot/controller/propertyeditors/propertyeditorsContext.xml"})
@PrepareForTest({HttpServletRequest.class, 
                 HttpServletResponse.class, 
                 ProductCriteriaPeriodService.class, 
                 HelpDeskService.class, 
                 WebUtils.class,
                 HttpSession.class})
    public class ProductCriteriaPeriodControllerTest {

        private final static String CRITERIA_FORM_ATTRIBUTE_KEY = "productCriteriaPeriodForm";

        private static final String PRODUCT_CRITERIA_PERIOD_CONFIRMATION_MSM = "productCriteriaPeriodConfirmationMessage";

        private static final String PRODUCT_CRITERIA_PERIOD_CONFIRMATION_MSM_KEY = "criteria.period.periodsHaveBeenUpdated";

        private static final String PRODUCT_CRITERIA_PERIOD_ERROR_MSM_KEY = "criteria.period.errorSaving";

        @Mock   
        private HttpServletRequest request;

        @Mock
        private HttpServletResponse response;

        @Mock
        private ProductCriteriaPeriodService productCriteriaPeriodService;

        @Mock
        protected HelpDeskService  helpDeskService ;        

        @Mock
        private HttpSession session;

        @InjectMocks
        private ProductcriteriaperiodController controller;


        @Before
        public void setUpTest() {               
            PowerMockito.mockStatic (WebUtils.class);
            PowerMockito.mockStatic (RequestContextUtils.class);        
        }

        @Test
        public void showFormTest() throws Exception {       

            when(helpDeskService.isHDRole()).thenReturn(true);

            Model model = new ExtendedModelMap();

            assertEquals("/criteria/productcriteriaperiod", controller.criteriaGracePeriod(request, model));

            Map<String, Object> attributes = model.asMap();

            assertTrue(attributes.containsKey(CRITERIA_FORM_ATTRIBUTE_KEY));

            ProductCriteriaPeriodForm criteriaGracePeriodForm = (ProductCriteriaPeriodForm)attributes.get(CRITERIA_FORM_ATTRIBUTE_KEY);

            assertNotNull(criteriaGracePeriodForm.getProductCriteriaPeriodsList());     
        }

        @Test
        public void saveOKTest( ) throws Exception {    

            Model model = new ExtendedModelMap();

            BindingResult result = mock(BindingResult.class);
            when(result.hasErrors()).thenReturn(false);

            assertEquals("/criteria/productcriteriaperiod", controller.save(new ProductCriteriaPeriodForm(), result, model));       

            Map<String, Object> attributes = model.asMap();

            assertTrue(attributes.containsKey(CRITERIA_FORM_ATTRIBUTE_KEY));
            assertTrue(attributes.containsKey(PRODUCT_CRITERIA_PERIOD_CONFIRMATION_MSM));
            assertEquals(attributes.get(PRODUCT_CRITERIA_PERIOD_CONFIRMATION_MSM), PRODUCT_CRITERIA_PERIOD_CONFIRMATION_MSM_KEY);

        }

        @Test
        public void saveNOKTest( ) throws Exception {   

            Model model = new ExtendedModelMap();

            BindingResult result = mock(BindingResult.class);
            when(result.hasErrors()).thenReturn(true);

            assertEquals("/criteria/productcriteriaperiod", controller.save(new ProductCriteriaPeriodForm(), result, model));       

            Map<String, Object> attributes = model.asMap();

            assertTrue(attributes.containsKey(CRITERIA_FORM_ATTRIBUTE_KEY));
            assertTrue(attributes.containsKey(PRODUCT_CRITERIA_PERIOD_CONFIRMATION_MSM));
            assertEquals(attributes.get(PRODUCT_CRITERIA_PERIOD_CONFIRMATION_MSM), PRODUCT_CRITERIA_PERIOD_ERROR_MSM_KEY);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`  instead of `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`